# How to read pool name from a Connection?

Tags: java, jdbc, websphere

I'm using a Connection via severals pools :

```
 DataSource ds = initialContext.lookup("poolname1");
 Connection cn = ds.getConnection();
 submethod1(cn);
 submethod2(cn);

 void submethod1(Connection cn)
 {
      // using connection
      // ..
 }
```

My question is: how to log "poolname" in submethods ? or similar informations about DataSource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this will help

```
getClientInfo()
```

or

```
getMetaData()
```

as mentionned in the [Official Java Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html)

Comment: Content available are not relevant to identify pool used. Furthermore, I tried to set ClientInfo with custom value and data source name, but it's not implemented (throw exception) :(

Comment: You can also try to maintain a mapping (`Map<Connection,String>`) between `Connection` instance and the pool name within a `ThreadLocal` that you can request from within your methods.

Comment: Accepted answer because I will use `Map<>` to store my pools names.

Answer (score 1):

The poolname in your example is actually a [JNDI Name](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/tutorial/1_3-fcs/doc/Resources2.html). This is generally a configuration which is configured in resource definition (e.q under  in tomcat config).

For your problem as @sourlcheck mentioned, its not possible as connection are not aware of their datasource.

Once way to solve your problem is to give label to the datasource. Most of the Pooled datasource implementations (e.q. [C3P0](http://sourceforge.net/projects/c3p0/)) offer a setter for setting up a name to the datasource. In C3P0 the datasournce class is [`ComboPooledDataSource`](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/apidocs/com/mchange/v2/c3p0/ComboPooledDataSource.html) and the method is `getDataSourceName()`. Once you get this name, it remains the same throughout its life cycle. But off course you need to introduce third party library

Comment: Using C3P0 may support DataSourceName in DataSource class, but does it forward this information in XXXConnection ? or maybe in its Meta/ClientInfo ?

Comment: Unfortunately no. As mentioned, connections are _not aware of the datasource_ they are requested from. That's how the SPIs are designed by SUN. Even the datasource name is also not there in standard _javax.sql.Datasource_ interface.

Answer (score 0):

You can't log "poolname" in methods that receive Connection. Connections don't know if they are pooled or served directly from non-pooling DataSource.

Also you can create and access your pool in many different ways, not all of them guaranteeing existence of "poolname".